# bulk data to ElasticSearch by powershell, but threw exception

Tags: powershell, elasticsearch

when i import the data to ElasticSearch by powershell, it always throw exception, any one can help me?

code:

```
$a = "{'create':{'_index':'kuyu','_type':'test','_id':'4'}}`n{'title': 'this is a test', 'text': 'test', 'date': '2016-01-02'}".Replace("'","`"")
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://localhost:9200/_bulk -Method POST -Body $a
```

the exception is:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;"}],"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;"},"status":400}
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://localhost:9200/_bulk -Method POST -Bo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're simply missing a newline at the end of your request, try this:

```
$a = "{'create':{'_index':'kuyu','_type':'test','_id':'4'}}`n{'title': 'this is a test', 'text': 'test', 'date': '2016-01-02'}`n".Replace("'","`"")
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://localhost:9200/_bulk -Method POST -Body $a
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, what worked was to change the has table into a string.
I got this error when trying to post a hash-table

```
$body = @{"key"="value"}
```

What worked for me was to convert to json before posting:
invoke-webrequest -method post -uri $uri -body (convertto-json $body) -headers $headers